# How much memory does alignment use in C?

Tags: c, memory, embedded

I have this program:

```
__attribute__((section(".graph"))) __attribute__((aligned(16)))
uint16_t FLASH_BUFFER2[FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE];

int main ()
{
  printf("Hallo World"\n);
}
```

When I run it, does it reserve `FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE * 16` bytes in memory?

Edit : The technically correct question is "does it reserve `FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE * 2 * 16` bytes in memory? (2 for `uint16_t` and 16 for alignment)"

Comment: hum, where else do you think it could be?

Comment: I have an embedded system with 1MB available RAM, the `FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE` is 65536. So this should take the entire memory. They gave me the code like this and I am wondering the same thing as you to be honest.

Comment: I guess this is done on purpose, the memory is certainly handled manually latter. this is probably because you do not have access to standard malloc/free (my guess)

Comment: Hm I do see 1 malloc() call in the code

Comment: obviously here there are not, but I imagine this is just a demonstration sample... that said I'm just trying to guess, the board must have some documentation you may look at to get accurate info.

Comment: If you align a `uint16_t` array on a multiple of 16 bytes, then it might be moved by up to 14 bytes (in a multiple of 2) from where it would have been placed without the alignment directive.  That's not a huge overhead, and presumably isn't an issue since the code would (apparently, normally) work even if it was not aligned on 16 byte boundaries.  You added the attribute for a reason, and space saving was not one of the reasons.   And **no**, it does not reserve `FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE * 16` bytes; it reserves `FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE * 2` bytes (assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`).

Comment: The title was missleading and not what you are asking. On a sidenote: don't use compiler features when there is a standard way.  `_Alignas` in this case.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite someone changed my title

Comment: Guess who and why I left a comment? I rolled back. Please think about it before you edit again.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite please don't change it again, I have no idea what the title your are placing means. My title is my honest question.

Comment: That's clearly not what you ask in the text nor what the answers are about. Including the one you accepted which indocates my edit was correct. So I change it and would apprechiate you leave it as-is. Titles should be as accurate as possible to aid future users find the correct subject. If you don't understand what it means, I recommend to do some research in your favourite C book and the fine gcc manual. If you have a different question, feel free to post a new one (you are not allowed to change your question once you got an answer). Edit: I corrected an obvious typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` just ensures that `FLASH_BUFFER2` is put on a 16-byte boundary. It will still reserve `FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(uint16_t)` bytes.

When I've used that attribute in the past, it was because the DMA controller or the mechanism used for writing to/from internal flash memory required that the RAM location be on a 16-byte boundary. Because you are doing this on an embedded system, you could be dealing with the same thing.

Comment: It is indeed used to a write to a FLASH and I figured the same reason

Answer (score 2):

> When I run it, does it reserve FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE * 16 bytes in memory?

No.  Type `uint16_t` is 16 *bits* wide, not 16 *bytes*.  Memory is indeed reserved for the array, but its size is `FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE * 2` bytes.

The `__attribute__` syntax you present is not part of standard C, so what it means depends on your compiler, but I see no reason whatever to think that it makes the array not actually have memory reserved for it after all, or that it changes the amount of memory reserved.  Probably, `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` simply ensures that the start address of the array is aligned on a 16-byte boundary.